# Hyper-V on Win Server 2008 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008, centos, hyper-v

Setup is as follows:

OS: Windows Server 2008 Standard
CPU: AMD 1055T (Six core AMD)

I'm attempting to install CentOS 6.4 (64-bit) VM on it. During the install, I run into issues.

The graphical installer does not seem to allow the mouse to work. (I'm RDPing to the host machine as I do not have console access).

The text installer seems to be fine, except for the fact that it's not detecting the IDE VHD hard-disk that is attached. The attached VHD is blank.

[image: Blank VHD labeled OpenAS]
Other example (likely the same issue):

When attempting to use OpenVPN access server's virtual appliance.  I get a lot of:

```
hv_vmbus: probe of vmbus_0_4 failed with error -110
```

At the end:

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/284b1cdc-c74d-47df-b7ea-1f99c01594e4 does not exist.  Dropping to shell.
```

[image: log]

Comment: 2008 is old and launched well before EL 6 was released. Why aren't you using a more modern host OS? You're also installing Ubuntu, not CentOS according to that screenshot.

Comment: I was showing two different install attempts. One CentOS 6.4, the other OpenVPN AS (Which is Ubuntu with OpenVPN AS pre-installed to it). This is what I have.

Comment: Again, you're using a very old hypervisor that doesn't list modern versions of EL or Ubuntu as supported. Upgrade your host.

Comment: +1 to MDMarra Upgrade both host to at least R2 (ideally - Windows Server 2012 R2) and get the most recent and decent *nix.

Answer (score 1):

How big is the drive? Due to Hyper-V restrictions it cannot be larger than 128GB. 
http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2013/01/how-to-install-centos-6-on-microsoft-hyper-v/

I note in the 2nd screenshot that vmbus_0_1, vmbus_0_2 and vmbus_0_4 error out, that vmbus_0_3 does not; from the first I'd assume this is the virtual CD drive (i.e. IDE bus 1 dev 1); This implies that the problem does not lie with the kernel that the CentOS installer is using; Also, the drive is identified somehow, as it references a UUID. May I suggest that running `/sbin/modinfo hv_vmbus` in the ash shell as well as `fdisk -l` may give firther insight.

Regardless, if the drive is greater that 128GB, try vcreating a new vhd <128GB;